# How to Get WWWForm in a WEB API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

In my WebApi i have this POST-Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [Route("api/user/save")]
    public void Save([FromBody]string userinfo)
    {
        using (var context = new CarWarsEntities())
        {
            var a = "";
        }
    }
```

And i call it in my Unity Project with this code:

```
    var url = "http://localhost:61506/api/user/save";
    var form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("EXP", GameControl.control.EXP);
    form.AddField("Health", GameControl.control.Health);
    form.AddField("Silver", GameControl.control.Silver);
    form.AddField("Gold", GameControl.control.Gold);
    form.AddField("Ammo", GameControl.control.Ammo);
    form.AddField("Nitro", GameControl.control.Nitro);
    var www = new WWW(url, form);
```

The call worked, but the userInfo string is always null. How can i get the WWWForm Fields in my WebApi?

This is the WebForm from fiddler:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have better luck doing something like this:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public int EXP {get; set}
    public int Health {get; set}
    public int Silver {get; set}
    public int Gold {get; set}
    public int Ammo {get; set}
    public int Nitro {get; set}
}
```

Then change your code slightly in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[Route("api/user/save")]
public void Save([FromBody]UserInfo userinfo)
{
    using (var context = new CarWarsEntities())
    {
        var a = "";
    }
}
```

That way, WebApi will map the form directly to an object for you.  I suspect that that it what it is trying to do for you now, but it's not able to do that.

If that doesn't work for you, look at the raw tab in Fiddler to see the JSON that is being sent.  It should match the UserInfo object.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You are right, but i have to write the json data and cannot use WWWForm. I got the hint from this thread: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/www-wwwform-to-post-json-data-to-server-solved.57490/